# Question to the Lax-Oleinik formula in Evans PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization

On p. 146 in Evans' book *Partial Differential equations* (AMS, 1998), it is written:

> Now for each $ x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $t > 0$, define the
>   point $y(x,t)$ to equal the smallest of those points $y$ giving the minimum of $t L(\frac{x−y}{t})+h(y)$.
>   Then the mapping $x → y(x,t)$ is nondecreasing and is thus continuous for all but at most countably many $x$. At a point $x$ of continuity of $y(·,t)$, $y(x,t)$ is the unique value of $y$ yielding the minimum.

I am trying to see why at a point $x$ of continuity of $y(·,t)$, $y(x,t)$ is the unique value of $y$ yielding the minimum.
Can someone help me with that?